# JS: Stretching mediaelement to fit page and getting rid of thin border

Tags: javascript, css, webrtc, mediaelement

The below is part of a script that loads two mediaelements with cams on a smartphone screen for two parties in a chat: A small view of oneself, and a big one supposed to fill the whole screen with the remote party. There are two things I would like to modify:
There´s a thin border around the element. I want to get rid of that.
The other problem is that the remote view doesn´t fill out the whole screen in the height. Could someone help me to succeed with these two issues? Thanks in advance:

```
connection.videosContainer = document.getElementById('videos-container');

connection.onstream = function(event) {

    var width = parseInt(connection.videosContainer.clientWidth);
   if (event.type === 'remote') { 
var   mediaElement = getMediaElement(event.mediaElement, {
        title: event.userid,
        buttons: [],
        width: width,
    showOnMouseEnter: false
    });

mediaElement.style.height = "100%";
mediaElement.style.width = "100%";
mediaElement.style.zIndex = "1";
mediaElement.style.position = 'absolute';
mediaElement.style.top = 0;
mediaElement.style.left = 0;


document.getElementById("videos-container").appendChild(mediaElement);

}
```

Comment: can you reproduce the current layout and post your html and any associated CSS?

Comment: This is the actual full code: https://lychee-custard-78219.herokuapp.com/demos/stackoverflow.html?roomid=PkKyo2yXPfI1

roomid can be anything. You just need to enter this into two browsers having the same roomid and then it will show what I mean - if you have a webcam or mobile cam that can work with two different browsers. If you don´t have that option, here´s a link to an image showing the problem: http://imgur.com/a/0iqpa